# How to make my flexslider hashtag compatible

Tags: jquery, hashtag, flexslider

does anyone one how can i share links like mypage.com/#slide1 or mypage.com/#slide2 
and call specific slides of my slider?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384472/hash-url-navigation-with-a-flexslider

I follow this guide and it works great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that i have an idea :

First you need to create a flexslider with navigation control

Then, with your hash tag named slide1, slide2, slideX, you know you want to go the (X-1) element so here's an example :

```
(jQuery.noConflict())(function($) {
    //Get your hash tag
    var loc = $(location).attr('href');
    var idx = 1;
    if(loc.lastIndexOf('#') != -1)
    {
        idx = loc.substr(loc.lastIndexOf('#')+1).replace('slide', '');
    }

    //verify that idx is really a number
    if(isNaN(idx-0))
    {
        idx = 1;
    }

    //Click on your nav (idx starts at 0)
    $('.flex-control-nav li:eq('+(idx-1)+') a').trigger('click');
    });
```

An other Way to do this would be to use startAt param like this :

```
(jQuery.noConflict())(function($) {
    //Get your hash tag
    var loc = $(location).attr('href');
    var idx = 1;
    if(loc.lastIndexOf('#') != -1)
    {
        idx = loc.substr(loc.lastIndexOf('#')+1).replace('slide', '');
    }

    //verify that idx is really a number
    if(isNaN(idx-0))
    {
        idx = 1;
    }

    $('#yourFlexSlider').flexslider ({
        startAt: idx
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Phillipe, i tried to use your code but i don't know why it's not working, this is my link. is it possible to have the #Slide on the url? Thanks for your help man. http://www.disennio.com/clientes/insigne

Comment: When you create the slider, you can use this : In your $('.galeria-videos').flexslider({ ... }); Add **startAt: idx** option. Thsi should initiate the slider at the slide specified in the URL. make sure you use slide in lowercase, it is case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks man. I want to trigger specific slides depending on the url for example if i type www.mypage.com/contact it will start with the <li id="contacto"> i've tried everything just can't find a solution. Thanks.